# Where is utilizing Spring Beans instead of Classic Java Objects

Tags: java, spring

I recently joined a company where I'm working extensively with Spring Boot microservices. I see how useful spring is for writing MVC code as well as managing cloud-deployed services with Spring Cloud. Something that has eluded me so far though is why we sometimes *do* and sometimes *don't* use Spring Beans. I don't see how labeling a class with `Component` makes it more useful to use than simply instantiating an object the classic way where we have more control over it. When we hand control over the object to Spring, it seems like it makes passing constructor parameters more difficult and only saves us from having to write a small bit of boiler plate code ie. `new MyObject()`. Even more confusing is why we sometimes would want to add a `@Bean`  method into a configuration class just so we can have a little more control over how the object is created.

It seems like we have a lot more flexibility and control over our objects if we just employ "classic" java design patterns instead of relying on Spring to manage beans for us.  Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: Spring beans reduce the development time and burden for maintaining the object creation. Whether you want to create a singleton or prototype all you can define in spring config. And you are thinking of a small project. Think you have a huge project with 1000 classes and you are managing the instance manually. This makes the complexity very high.
I suggest you through the spring documents. It will help you understand better

Comment: Read about "dependency injection".

Answer (score 0):

> Even more confusing is why we sometimes would want to add a @Bean
> method into a configuration class just so we can have a little more
> control over how the object is created

**@Component/@service/@Repository and @Bean** are quite different things, don't get confused about these 2.

**@Component** is used to auto-detect and auto-configure beans using classpath scanning. There's an implicit one-to-one mapping between the annotated class and the bean.

**So @Component is used for component scanning and automatic wiring**

**@Bean** is used to explicitly declare a single bean, rather than letting Spring do it automatically as above. It decouples the declaration of the bean from the class definition and lets you create and configure beans exactly how you choose.

**When should you use @Bean?**

Sometimes automatic configuration is not an option. When? Let's imagine that you want to wire components from 3rd-party libraries (you don't have the source code so you can't annotate its classes with @Component), so automatic configuration is not possible.